# Claims Aware MVC App in 2012 - Logging off

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, wif

I created an MVC 4 application in .net 4.5 and installed the Identity and Access tool so that I could create a claims aware application. I configured the application so that it uses the new LocalSTS that comes with 2012, so it doesn't create an STS website like it used to in 2010.

How do I support a log off scenario in my application? Is there a method I can call like `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`?

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy, just call the SignOut method on the WSFederationAuthenticationModule:

```
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut("/MyPostSignoutRedirectUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

To process a sign-out request, perform the following steps:

1. After clicking on the sign-out link, clear the federation cookie:
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(stateKey);
2. Redirect the browser to the simulated issuer with a WS-Federation sign-out parameter as the action:

```
https://RelyingParty/SsoLogout.aspx?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=...
```

The WS-Federation command—wa=wsignout1.0 is used
to sign out from the issuer.

1. Retrieve the list of RPs from the cookie and send the sign-out clean-up command to
   each of them:

```
 https://RelyingParty1/SsoLogout.aspx?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0,
```

```
https://RelyingParty2/SsoLogout.aspx?wa= wsignoutcleanup1.0,
```

```
https://RelyingParty3/SsoLogout.aspx?wa= wsignoutcleanup1.0
```

This allows all the relying parties to perform the sign-out operation.

IT Works as follow:

The wsignout1.0 and wsignoutcleanup1.0 actions defined in the wa GET parameter
are well understood by relying parties adhering to the WS-Federation Passive Requestor
Profile. These actions allow a sign-out operation from all the RPs in the realm.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the to persistent cookies and on sign out click or session end expire the fedauth cookies?

Persistent Cookies on RP:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation
            persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
        <cookieHandler 
          persistentSessionLifetime="60.0:0:0" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

And Expire the Cookies

```
    var c = Request.Cookies["FedAuth"];
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(c);

    c = Request.Cookies["FedAuth1"];
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(c);
```

You will need to redirect after this.